# Issue with building multiselect user control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, linq, sumoselect.js

I'm building a MultiSelect UserControl in vb.net
i have the following problem to populate my multiselect i have created.
Example code is below

Javascript of SumoSelect() is client side everything is working only thing i need is programmatically set selected values or not :)

https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/

**Multiselect.ascx**

```
      Property SelectedValues() As String()
      Get
         Return selValues.Value.Split(",")
      End Get
      Set(value As String())
         For i As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
             If i = 0 Then
                 selValues.Value = value(i)
             Else
                 selValues.Value += "," + value(i)
             End If
         Next
     End Set
   End Property       


    Sub New()
       Items = New Dictionary(Of Object, Object)
    End Sub


    Public Items As Dictionary(Of Object, Object)

    Private Function CreateItems() As String

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

        For Each item In Items

           sb.AppendFormat("<option value=""{0}"">{0}</option>", item.Key, item.Value)

        Next

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function

'' selValues is a HiddenField clientside
```

**Set SelectedValues:**

```
MultiSelect1.SelectedValues() = New String() {"Banana Color", "Green Color", "Juice Color"}
```

***Population:***

```
 For Each item In PjtColor.Fetch(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
      MultiSelect1.Items.Add(item.ColorName, item.ColorName)
 Next
```

I need to compare SelectedValues(String Array) with Items(Dict)
to set `sb.AppendFormat("<option value=""{0}"" selected=""selected"">{0}</option>", item.Key, item.Value)` to selected and when not matching to

```
sb.AppendFormat("<option value=""{0}"">{0}</option>", item.Key, item.Value)
```

Based on: http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html

I render it into a Literal which outputs the `<options></option>` inside the `<select></select>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say based on that GitHub project but you don't initialize the `SumoSelect()` anywhere.

Comment: I did man on client side did not post that one :)

Comment: everything is working fine but now i want the selected option in the list i need to compare my populated Dict Items with SelectedValues String array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the question to my Answhere

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To SelectedValues.Count - 1
        SelectedItems.Add(SelectedValues(i), SelectedValues(i))
    Next

    For Each item In Items
        If SelectedItems.ContainsKey(item.Key) Then
            sb.AppendFormat("<option value=""{0}"" selected=""selected"">{0}</option>", item.Key, item.Value)
        Else
            sb.AppendFormat("<option value=""{0}"">{0}</option>", item.Key, item.Value)
        End If
    Next
```